# Capture photos in interval from canvas

Tags: javascript, memory, canvas, out-of-memory, setinterval

I have a script that allows me to show in canvas the webcam and 'download' a specific frame within some intervals.
I am having trouble when time parameters are big (30 minutes of captures every 2 seconds). It works smoothly for about 15 minutes and then crashes (firefox closes with out of memory error). Also, after restarting firefox sometimes many 0 byte photos are taken during a 3-4 mins and then starts working again. I am running this in an old 2 GB RAM machine placed in the lab, is there a way to reduce memory usage?

Here is the piece of code with parameters and the function `realizarCapturas`.
I can add the resting code but I think the part to optimize should be this one.

```
  var frecuenciaComienzoCaptura = 1; // how long till next capture
  var frecuenciaCaptura = 3; //seconds between photos
  var duracion = 5; // amount of photos to capture

  function realizarCapturas(){
    var i = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(i <= duracion){
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);

        var imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
        imagen.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        var now = new Date();
        var filename = formatNumber(now.getHours()) + "-" + formatNumber(now.getMinutes()) + "-" + formatNumber(now.getSeconds());

        imagen.download = filename + ".png"; // Make sure the browser downloads the image
        imagen.click(); // Trigger the click
        i = i+1;
      }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, frecuenciaCaptura * 1000);
  }



  setInterval(function(){
    realizarCapturas();
  }, frecuenciaComienzoCaptura * 1000 * 60 * 60);

  realizarCapturas(); 


}, false);
```

Comment: You might be stacking up unfinished operations. Try refactoring using a single `requestAnimationFrame` loop instead of multiple intervals. Monitor you resource usage with the Dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule NEVER use `setInterval` as it can be a source of call stack overflows which are very difficult to detect in code.

Your problem is that you are not clearing all the intervals you are generating and thus every 3 seconds you are creating a new interval event. Eventually the time it takes to run the little bit of code will be longer than than can be managed by all the interval events you have created and thus each interval will continue to push their events onto the call stack but will not get a chance to be run until more intervals have been place on the stack eventually causing the crash. Nor does setInterval guarantee the time between events are accurate.

Use `setTimeout` instead. That way you will only ever generate event as needed and you do not have to keep a handle to turn off events.

Below is your code written so that you will never have a call stack overflow.

```
var frecuenciaComienzoCaptura = 1 * 1000* 60 * 60; // how long till next capture
var frecuenciaCaptura = 3 * 1000; //seconds between photos
var duracion = 5; // amount of photos to capture
var counter = 0;
// the capture function
var captura = function () {    
    counter = counter + 1;
    if(counter < duracion){  // do we need more images?
        // only create timer events as needed.
        setTimeout(captura, frecuenciaCaptura); //set time till next image
    }
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    var imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
    imagen.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    var now = new Date();
    var filename = formatNumber(now.getHours()) + "-" + formatNumber(now.getMinutes()) + "-" + formatNumber(now.getSeconds());

    imagen.download = filename + ".png"; // Make sure the browser downloads the image
    imagen.click(); // Trigger the click
}

function realizarCapturas() {
    // request next batch of captures by only creating one timer event as we need
    setTimeout(realizarCapturas,frecuenciaComienzoCaptura);
    counter = 0; // reset counter
    captura(); // capture timages
}

// start captures.
realizarCapturas();
```

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly during this afternoon, it also seems easier on the memory requirements because images get created almost at the same time that the actual time